# How do I conform a struct with a generic property to equatable?

Tags: swift, generics, equatable

I have the following struct:

```
struct IndexAndItem<ItemType> {
    let index: Int
    let item: ItemType
}
```

I need to conform `IndexAndItem<MyClass>` to `Equatable`.

`MyClass` already conforms to `Equatable` however when I try:

```
extension IndexAndItem: Equatable where ItemType == MyClass {
    internal static func == (lhs: IndexAndItem, rhs: IndexAndItem) -> Bool {
        lhs.item == rhs.item
    }
}
```

I get an error:

> Method '==' must be declared public because it matches a requirement in public protocol 'Equatable'

Changing it to `public` it then throws another error asking to replace `public` with `internal`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Xcode 12.5. Won't let me mark as internal

Comment: Why not simply `struct IndexAndItem<ItemType : Equatable> : Equatable {...` without the extension?

Comment: @vadian I am using extension so conformance only happens in the Test target

Comment: @Kex You're not doing it right, you should not augment your app code only for testing purposes. It might feel less noisy, but you're actually introducing false expectations to people that stumble that unit testing code, expecting for the production struct to be equatable. Use a helper method instead, or if it makes sense, add the `Equatable` conformance to the app code.

Answer (score 0):

As *@vadian* suggested above, you could do this -

```
struct IndexAndItem<ItemType: Equatable>: Equatable {
    let index: Int
    let itemType: ItemType
}
```

This way, you don't have to worry about more `ItemType` types later being used with `IndexAndItem`.

---

If you just want to know how to make it work the way you are trying, here's how it worked for me for both `internal` types.

```
class MyClass: Equatable {
    let flag: Bool
    init(flag: Bool) { self.flag = flag }
    static func == (lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
        lhs.flag == rhs.flag
    }
}

struct IndexAndItem<ItemType> {
    let index: Int
    let itemType: ItemType
}

// Restricted to one type `MyClass`
extension IndexAndItem: Equatable where ItemType == MyClass {
}

// Open to all types that conform to `Equatable`
extension IndexAndItem: Equatable where ItemType: Equatable {
}
```

As long as your `ItemType` conforms to `Equatable`, compiler can synthesize the conformance for you. You don't need to implement any method.

Comment: The `Restricted to one type `MyClass` . how do you define `static func == (lhs: IndexAndItem, rhs: IndexAndItem) -> Bool` ? I get `Cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant` when I use `return lhs.item = rhs.item`

Comment: You don't need to define the `static func ==`  in this case, compiler can synthesize it's implementation automatically. That's what the last line in the answer says.